# Force static linking of library linked to Xcode target?

Tags: xcode, gcc, linker

My Xcode target links against hdf5 library (using the Link Binary with Libraries build phase). libhdf5 is installed using MacPorts, thus /opt/local/lib contains both the dynamic (.dylib) and static (.a) versions of the library.

The text output from the build shows that there is, as expected, a `-lhdf5` in the linking step of the build. gcc seems to take the dynamic linked library over the static, however. Is there any way to force gcc (via a compiler switch or via Xcode) to statically link with libhdf5.a?

The only solution I've found is to copy libhdf5.a to the project (or other) directory and link against that copy, thus avoiding having dynamic and static versions in the same location.

Comment: I would love to see some updated answers to this question with instructions for more recent versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In reaction to your comment on Eduard Wirch' answer: you can also control static linking for this one library only, if you replace -lhdf5 by -l/full/path/to/libhdf5.a

Comment: It looks like the "-l" actually needs to be omitted, per the other answer given.  If I include it the linker gives me "ld: library not found for -l/opt/local/lib/libhdf5.a", while simply passing it the path "/opt/local/lib/libhdf5.a" without a flag works fine.

Comment: How would one fix this when using automake?

Answer (score 16):

Had this exact same problem and despite this being an old post, I thought I'd share what I had to do to make this work.

Usually you do just provide the switch '-static' to the linker however, with Xcode this causes all libs including the crt to be linked statically. I got the error:

```
can't locate file for: -lcrt0.o
```

When I tried above.

What worked for me was to replace:

```
-lmylib
```

With:

```
/path/to/libmylib.a
```

> **Note** that the `-l` is dropped.

Answer (score 3):

My case with Xcode 4.5:

When I drag and drop a static C library (a 3rd party library compiled with GNU Autotools) to project's frameworks (`Project Navigator > Frameworks`) the linker seems to thinks that's a dynamic library and adds `-L -l` flags:

```
-L/path/to/libfoodir -lfoo
```

The linking fails because there is no `/path/to/libfoodir/libfoo.dylib`.
The linker command can be seen from:

```
Log Navigator > select a Build log > select a Link line and expand it
```

The linking succeeds when I add a full path (`/path/to/libfoodir/libfoo.a`) to the linker settings:

```
Targets > Build Settings (all) > Other linker flags
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the "-static" switch for linking:
[GCC link options](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-3-Manual/gcc/link-options.html)

Comment: Will this force static linking of all libraries, or can it's application be controlled on a per-library basis?

Comment: Actually it will link all libraries static.

Answer (score 0):

Under XCode 11.3.1, targeting MacOS

Tried to add absolute lib path to `Other linker flags`. But that doesn't work. So I copied required *.a files (ln -s may also work) to project dir and it worked like a charm.