# library not found for -lstdc++.6 in Xcode 10

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cordova, lib

I am not able to build Cordova based iOS app in Xcode Beta and GM version Because In this project used `-lstdc++.6`. Why because Apple has deprecated `-lstdc++.6` this library in the newer Xcode version.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

So I have removed this library from the `Link Binary With Libraries` and also I have added `libc++` this library.

After That I am facing this issue linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

[image]

Could you any one help me how to solve this library issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694822/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9

Comment: @DannyLau I have tried your ways still i am facing the issue. After removed -libstdc++ library and added -libc++ now i am getting symbol not found for architecture x86_64 issue. see my second attached screenshot.

Comment: Copying and pasting text instead of a screenshot makes that information more accessible to the people from whom you are asking help. (It's probably easier for you as well since you don't have to worry about cropping an image well.)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ BUT Changing produces compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927007/libstdc-is-deprecated-move-to-libc-wdeprecated-but-changing-produces-com), but it looks like dupes cannot be flagged when there is an open bounty? I re-posted a summary of the dupe's answer here to make it more readily accessible.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ \[-Wdeprecated\] BUT Changing produces compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927007/libstdc-is-deprecated-move-to-libc-wdeprecated-but-changing-produces-com)

Answer (score 2):

Rebuild `libMAFLogger` with the new library dependency.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21379414)

Comment: @VineethSai Pardon me, but you are wrong. This is not a critique of the question nor a request for clarification. The question is "how to solve this library issue". The issue can be solved by rebuilding the library. Hence my answer.