# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have facing the problem in my ios project. symbols not found for architecture x86_64 in xcode `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: are you running in simulator ? try it in real device

Comment: your SDK is only support for device

Comment: kindly provide more information , like what happen when you run on device, this is your own dynamic framework or you using third party framework ? for dynamic framework you need to add build script to make unirversal framework build that will run both sim and device.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh: My existing project used -lstdc++ library. Now Xcode 10 not support that library. So I have remove this library instead of that I have added -lc++ library like able suggested in xcode 10.  After that I am facing the above issue.

Comment: What is `MAFConsoleLogger`? Seems to be a private library. Well, it needs to be rebuilt again without stdc++, and added again to your project. Also, avoid duplicating your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371265/library-not-found-for-lstdc-6-in-xcode-10

Comment: Have you find the solution to this I am also having the same issues with a unity project after exporting as iOS.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases this points to one or more missing references to frameworks in the section Linked Frameworks And Libraries in the Targets settings of the app in Xcode.

To find out which framework reference should be added:

- Right-click on the error in the build time errors list
- Choose 'Reveal in Log',
- Search in the log for 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64'
- A list of undefined 'symbols' (mostly class methods and properties) is displayed
- To find out which framework reference should be added, select such undefined symbol, right-click and choose Search with Google
- In most cases you'll end up in the documentation of Apple, which should give a clue about the related framework
- Add the framework in the section Linked Frameworks And Libraries by clicking on the + button.
- Build the app.
- If necessary, repeat this procedure for remaining undefined 'symbols'.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem when running the unit tests for an application that had a custom framework as a dependency.  The application was running fine but not its unit tests (I was getting the exact error shown above).  I resolved it as follows:
- Select the unit test target for the application (e.g. Tests)
- Under "Testing" section enable "Allow testing Host Application APIs"

Comment: Note this started happening as soon as I installed Xcode 10.0.  Everything was working fine up until then.

Comment: you made my day dude :)

Comment: :) can you accept the answer if it solved your problem @ChetanDobariya

Answer (score 0):

**ld: symbol(s) not found for**

It is compile time error that is cased by `Static Linker`

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for ...
...
Undefined symbols for
```

You should add a library or framework to `General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section

[image]

Comment: this was the answer for me - my subproject was a framework, and I had the target set to just iOS instead of iOS + OSX